# Suppose A is an m x n matrix, such that ker(A) = 0. prove that $A^TA$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

Ok I did most of the work but i need someone to check my work.

1) Since we know that $Ker(A) = 0$, then this implies that $Ker(A^TA) = 0$

2) if the kernel of $A^TA$ is $0$, then $dim(ker(A^TA)) = 0$

3) Now, if we use the rank nullity theorem,

$Rank(A^TA) + dim(ker(A^TA)) = n$

$n + 0 = n$

4) We can clearly see that $Rank(A^TA)$ is equal to n

5) According to the invertible matrix theorem, one of its conditions clearly states that if a matrix has full rank, then it is invertible.

Thus we conclude that $A^TA$ is invertible

Is what i just did enough to prove that $A^TA$ is invertible? did i make a mistake in my logic somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to see it:

$A^TA$ is invertible if and only if

$\ker A^TA = \{0\}. \tag 1$

If

$x \in \ker A^TA, \tag 2$

then

$A^TAx = 0; \tag 3$

thus

$x^TA^TAx = 0, \tag 4$

or

$(Ax)^T(Ax) = 0, \tag 5$

which implies

$Ax = 0, \tag 6$

or

$x \in \ker A = \{0\}; \tag 7$

thus

$x = 0, \tag 8$

so (1) binds.

Comment: I dont understand how you went from step (3) to step (4)... where did the $x^T$ come from?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master:  once you have $A^TAx = 0$, $x^TA^TAx = 0$ certainly follows, right?  In fact, $y^TA^TAx = 0$ for any $y$.  Knowing this, I just *chose* to left multiply by $x^T$ because I knew it would work, that is, it would lead to (5) which basically says that $(Ax) \cdot (Ax) = 0$, which forces (6).

Comment: Ok i understand that now.. but can you clarify on step (5). How is it that $(Ax)^T(Ax) = 0$ is the same as $(Ax)(Ax) = 0$?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master:  If by $(Ax)(Ax)$ you mean $(Ax) \cdot (Ax)$, then note that for any vector $y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)^T$, $y^T y = \sum_1^n y_i^2 = y \cdot y$.  Does this help?

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure, sir!

Comment: One more question! How is it that you went from $(Ax) . (Ax) = 0$ to $(Ax) = 0$? it seems to me that $(Ax) . (Ax)$ is the dot product so i would assume that the result would be some scalar.

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master:  From $y \cdot y = y^Ty = \sum_1^n y_i^2$. Since $y \cdot y$ is the sum of squares of the components of $y$, it can only be zero if $y$ is.  Now let $y = Ax$.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine to me. The other minor piece is that $A^{T}A$ is square. So you have a square matrix with full rank, so it's invertible.

A worse way to prove this is using the singular value decomposition of $A = U\Sigma V^{T}$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with all positive entries. Thus $A^{T}A = V \Sigma^2 V^{T}$ which is invertible since all the eigenvalues $\Sigma_{ii}^2$ are nonzero.

Comment: Is there a better way to prove $A^TA$ is invertible? I figured that my way was not the best way to do just that.